# Telling a for loop to print out a different title for each iteration of [i] in R

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I'm working on cleaning up a markdown file of a project that worked on for a local research organization. This was my first real-world project and my first time utilizing a for loop. The goal was to print out 12 maps of a particular set of variables using ggplot2. The loop works and prints out the maps needed with the legend title, caption, and subtitle. However when it prints out the title (each map gets a unique title), the title prints "NA"[map of the first iteration of [i](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LQx1.png) instead of the title. My suspicion, as of now, is that when a title in the `title1` variable is called, it tries to match the variable name with the first title in the list of `title1`. When there is no match, it prints the title as NA. Is there something I'm missing in the code or is this loop written completely wrong? I would love any valuable feedback as I'm still learning the intricacies of for-loops. See the sample code below:

```
out_dir = "../mapping/results/Birth_Maps_v2/"

for (i in 18:29)   {
  vari <- names(birth2018_join)[i]

  title1 <- c("Births by Food Stamp utilization (2018)",
              "Births by Hispanic Origin (2018)",
              "Births By Inadequate Parental Care (2018)",
              "Births by Low Birth Weight (2018) \n (less than 2,500g)",
              "Births by Marital Status (2018)",
              "Births by Maternal Age (15-19) (2018)",
              "Births by Maternal Education \n (High School Graduate or Greater, 2018)",
              "Births by Maternal Race - White (2018)",
              "Births by Medicaid Utilization (2018)",
              "Births by Preterm (2018) \n (less than 37 weeks gestational age)",
              "Births by Very Low Birth Weight (2018) \n (less than 1,500g)",
              "Births by WIC Utilization (2018)")[i]
  legend1 <- "Rate per 100 Live Births" 
  sub_title <- "Missouri Counties 2018"
  note      <- "Source: Missouri Vital Statistics - Birth Data, 2018. NA's are values that are unstable due
  to low counts, or are suppressed for the privacy of the resident."
  
  gg = ggplot(data = birth2018_join) + 
    geom_sf(aes_string(fill = vari)) +
    theme_map() +
    labs(title = title1,
         subtitle = sub_title,
         caption = note) +
    theme(legend.position = "right") + 
    theme(plot.caption = element_text(size = 7, hjust = 0, face= "italic"),
          plot.title.position = "plot",
          plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0)) +
    custom_fill(name = legend1)

ggsave(paste0(out_dir, i, ".png"), dpi = 350, plot = gg)
}
```

Comment: Does `[i - 17]` work when selecting the title?

Comment: That worked! Thank you! so I should have specified [I - 17] to tell the loop to disregard the first 17 variables in the data set?

Comment: In your loop, `i` will take on the values 18, 19, 20, etc. But you want to select the titles from your character vector at indices 1, 2, 3, etc. respectively. `[i - 17]` corrects that. As an advanced tip, many R users (me included) think that loops are not a good way to handle iteration in R, and prefer to use functions and maps instead...

Comment: OH, I completely understand. There were a lot of things that went wrong with the project and my lead was under the gun to something out quickly as the client kept moving around due dates and we were having difficulty just obtaining the data. I don't prefer to use loops in this way either. My goal is to just clean up what I have to show employers what was done.